# FileNotFoundException Access Denied

Tags: java, file, jsp, tomcat, filenotfoundexception

I'm having a little issue with `FileNotFoundException`.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\folder\folder\folder (Access is denied)     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:416)
>       at org.apache.jsp.control_jsp._jspService(control_jsp.java:2715)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>       at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>       at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>       at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:206)
>       at
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:179)
>       at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>       at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>       at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>       at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>       at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>       at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>       at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>       at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>       at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

The file is uploaded from a web form. I don't think there is a reason for the code above this.

Code:

```
String itemName = item.getName();
if (itemName.indexOf("\\") != -1) {
    int slash = itemName.lastIndexOf("\\");
    if (slash != -1) {
        itemName = itemName.substring(slash + 1);
    }
    // I think Windows doesn't like /'s either
    int slash2 = itemName.lastIndexOf("/");
    if (slash2 != -1) {
        itemName = itemName.substring(slash2 + 1);
    }
    // In case the name is C:foo.txt
    int slash3 = itemName.lastIndexOf(":");
    if (slash3 != -1) {
        itemName = itemName.substring(slash3 + 1);
    }
}
File savedFile = new File(config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "filing/" + itemName);
item.write(savedFile);
```

This happens for more folders in my web app.

I searched the internet for solutions but the only thing I found about this specific error is that:

The folder is inaccessible like when it's write protected (Read Only) but my folders have access to all except Special Permissions and Full Control.

By the way all my folders are created dynamically in the code.

P.S The code is not mine, I'm just finding these errors in my webapp stderr everyday, it doesn't seem to create a problem but I would like to solve it.

Has anyone experienced the same problem or can help out?

I know it's not really serious question but it never hurts to ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Files and folders under `C:\Program Files` and `C:\Program Files (x86)` often require administrative permissions to modify them. Change the `webapp` directory and see if the problem persists.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\folder\folder\folder       is that really the path to your file?  Is  "folder"  the name of your web app?

Comment: no that just a name a gave for the question

Comment: I guess that we need to see the code.

Comment: I've edited the question, please see code

Comment: Did you print out itemName and the path that you passed to new File()?  Are they what you expected? Show us examples of each.

Comment: The path is created correctly and the permissions are correct as well. But the error still pops up.

Comment: I never had this problem writing to a file in my web apps. You could create a small test servlet that just creates a file and writes some text into it. You could post it and we could test it on our machines.

Comment: @rickz It writes to a file ok, it just pops the error. Maybe when trying to access the folder. Not sure. I created a small test servlet and everything seems to work fine. I can write and read the text.

Comment: Is there an issue if the folders are created in the projects directory? Or May it be an issue with memory or something, I've been having a lot of them the past month (all solved now).